# Euler's Method Python Variable Input Type

Tags: python, variables, input

I'm having an issue with the following code. It's currently in progress but a large problem that I'm running into is that my input of a function returns an error no matter what type of input I have tried. It either returns with an issue with the error type, or an issue of x not being defined if I enter a function such as x.

```
f = raw_input("Please enter function: y' = ")
x0 = float(raw_input("Please enter the initial x value: "))
y0 = float(raw_input("Please enter the initial y value: "))
xmax = float(raw_input("Please enter the value of x at which to approximate the solution: "))
h = float(raw_input("Please enter the step size: "))
showall = int(raw_input("Would you like to see all steps (1) or only the approximate solution (2)? "))

def f(x,y):
    value = f
    return (value)

def euler(x0,y0,h,xmax):
    x=x0; y=y0; xd=[x0]; yd=[y0];

    while x<xmax:
        y = y + h*f(x,y)
        yd.append(y)
        x=x+h
        xd.append(x)
    return(xd,yd)

(xvals,yvals) = euler(x0,y0,h,xmax)



if showall == 1:
    print ""
    print "x_n y_n"
    for uv in zip(xvals, yvals):
        print uv[0],uv[1]
elif showall == 2:
    print ""
    print "x_n y_n"
    print xvals, yvals  
else:
    print ""
    print "There has been an error with your choice of what to see; showing all steps."
    print ""
    print "x_n y_n"
    for uv in zip(xvals, yvals):
        print uv[0],uv[1]

print " "       
plotask = int(raw_input("Would you like to see a plot of the data? Yes (1); No (2) "))

if plotask == 1:
    print "1"
elif plotask == 2:
    pass
else:
    print ""
    print "Could not understand answer; showing plot."
```

Any help would be appreciated.

The error and trace is the following:

```
   File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\euler.py", line 25, in <module>
      (xvals,yvals) = euler(x0,y0,h,xmax)
   File "C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\euler.py", line 19, in euler
      y = y + h*f(x,y)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'
```

Comment: Show the exact error message and stack trace, please.

Comment: Post has been updated to show error and trace

Comment: I'm new here and wasn't aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that your function `f` is using the same name as the formula string you're collecting in the first line of your code. However, just fixing the name won't do what you want, I don't think.

Your `f` function will need to evaluate the formula, in order to get a numeric result. I think you want this:

```
formula = raw_input("Please enter function: y' = ")

def f(x, y):
    return eval(formula)
```

While this works, I do want to point out that using `eval` is generally not recommended practice, especially when the string you're evaluating comes from a user. That's because it can include arbitrary Python code, which will be run. `eval('__import__(os).system("rm -Rf *")')` could really ruin your day (don't run this code!).

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem! Regarding using eval, it would be alright as long as the user doesn't enter some type of python code, correct?

Comment: @danielu13 If you wish to make a calculator that does not use eval (-> is safe), look up PLY for python. It's a lexer/parser and is great for doing things like writing expression parsers (I've written one in it)

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```
def f(x,y):
    value = f
    return (value)
```

Can be seen to return a function. In particular, it does nothing except return itself, `f`. (note that `f` is different from `f()` or `f(x,y)`

```
y = y + h*f(x,y)
```

evaluates to

```
y = y + h*f
```

which is an error, as `f` is a function and you cannot multiply a function by a number (as opposed to the RESULT of evaluating a function call - e.g. if `f(x,y)` returns a number, then your code will work)

Comment: I thought that was the issue, but if I try substitution a function directly for for the value as in `value = x*y` instead of `f = x*y; value = f` it works. Is there another way to do this where I can prompt for an input?

Comment: That is because when you do `value = x*y` `value` is a number (the result of evaluating `x*y`, but `value = f` makes `value` a function (the result of evaluating `f` is to return `f`, which is a function). To turn a function into the result it returns, you have to evaluate it, which requires calling it, as in `f()` or `f(x+y)`.

Comment: Thanks. It just kind of hit me what you were trying to explain as soon as I posted the comment. I understand now.